# How I can prove that 2-CNF is not NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete

I want to know how I can show that 2-CNF is not NP-hard or NP complete?

Comment: If it can be done in a pre-determined number of steps then it is not NP-Hard, or NP-Complete.

Comment: Try cstheory.stackexchange.com, but show some effort first.

Answer (score 2):

2-CNF satisfiability is known to be in P. So if you were able to prove it is not NP-complete, it would follow that P ≠ NP. Thus, no one knows how to prove this.